# Change Month Value in FormDate CodeIgniter Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, lang

I'm using additional [Form Date](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/FormDate) library of CodeIgniter. But, I wanna change the month value, for example:

```
January change to Januari
February change to Febuari
March change to Maret
and so on....
```

In this library, the default lang is en_US. Can I change it to Indonesia language,.? or how can I change the month value,.?
thanks,.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CI language files:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code https://gist.github.com/3509222

```
function custom_date($timestamp = NULL, $format = 'd F, Y')
{
    $l = array('', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jum\'at', 'Sabtu', 'Minggu');
    $F = array('', 'Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember');

    $return = '';
    if(is_null($timestamp)) { $timestamp = mktime(); }
    for($i = 0, $len = strlen($format); $i < $len; $i++) {
        switch($format[$i]) {
            case '\\' :
                $i++;
                $return .= isset($format[$i]) ? $format[$i] : '';
                break;
            case 'l' :
                $return .= $l[date('N', $timestamp)];
                break;
            case 'F' :
                $return .= $F[date('n', $timestamp)];
                break;
            default :
                $return .= date($format[$i], $timestamp);
                break;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```